# How to specify a datasource for a droplist field in sitecore 8.0 template

Tags: templates, datasource, field

I am using `Sitecore 8.0` where I have created a template with field droplist field type and I want to give datasource for it where it references another template datasource. And we have Multiple Sites under the Sitecore Content node.

[image]

Below is what i need to acheive :

Have 2 templates FormFields template and the other one is Field type template. FormFields template has a field name "FieldType" with data type droplist which references the datasource which is been created using the Field type template.

We have multiple site nodes and same datasource of field types needs to be created in each site. For testing purpose i have the direct path of one of the site and for the field type it started showing the field types data in the form of dropdown. Same template i have to use it for other site nodes too so i am trying to write a query for datasource .

Tried below queries for field type, but both of them didn't work. :

```
1.DataSource=query:$site-root::/Site Content/Modules/CFieldTypes

2.query://*[@@id = '{59E50241-DBF5-4ED0-A3DA-852081022A5F}']
```

Here is the FormField template :

[image]

Here is datasource for Field types

[image]

As of now i have given the direct path to the datasource so it is looking like below scrnshot

[image]

Want to use same template for all the site nodes so i have tried different queries but didn't work.

Can anyone please suggest what I need to do?

Thank you

Comment: You need to specify in more detail what you need to achieve, and exaclty what "didn't work".

Comment: Updated my question @MarkCassidy

Answer (score 0):

Droplist fields support Sitecore Query.

[image]

Have a look on this link and see how to build a Sitecore query:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/SdnArchive/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.html

For your second query it should work :

Attribute: [@@id]

Description: Item ID.

```
Query Example:

query://*[@@id = '{787EE6C5-0885-495D-855E-1D129C643E55}']

Searches through the entire content tree and returns an Item with the mentioned ID.
```

Is not 100% clear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you please check have updated my question @Vlad lobagiu

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='RootTemplate']/Data/DatasourceItem
```

I tried it on my instance with **Droplist** field and it's working.

Comment: Hi @Rishiraj , tried the above query by replacing my root template name but it didn't work

Comment: did you set "/Data/DatasourceItem" as well, it denotes your datasource item location under website node.

Comment: Yeah i have changed that one too